# Rails 4 ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

I'm getting this error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Manufacturers#index` along with `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"cars"} missing required keys: [:manufacturer_id]` for the following code. I have looked around and can't find the answer for this one.

cars_controller.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @cars = Car.all
  end

  def show
   @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])
   @car = Car.new(params[:id])
   @car.manufacturer = @manufacturer
 end

 def create
  @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:manufacturer_id])
  @car = Car.new(cars_params)
  @car.manufacturer = @manufacturer

 if @car.save
  flash[:notice] = "You have successfully created a car"
  redirect_to manufacturer_cars_path
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end

private

def cars_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:make, :color, :year, :mileage, :description, :country)
end
end
```

manufacturers_controller.rb

```
class ManufacturersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @manufacturers = Manufacturer.all
  end

  def show
    @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find(params[:id])
    @car = Car.new
  end

  def new
    @manufacturer = Manufacturer.new
  end

  def create
    @manufacturer = Manufacturer.new(manufacturer_params)

    if @manufacturer.save
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully created a new manufacturer"
      redirect_to root_path(@manufacturer)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Please try again"
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def manufacturer_params
    params.require(:manufacturer).permit(:name, :country)
  end
end
```

models/car.rb

```
  class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :manufacturer

    validates :make, presence: true
    validates :color, presence: true
    validates :year, presence: true
    validates :mileage, presence: true
    validates :country, presence: true
  end
```

models/manufacturer.rb

```
  class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cars

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :country, presence: true
  end
```

this link works in my cars/index.html.erb `<%= link_to "Add Car", new_manufacturer_car_path %>` but not in my layouts/application.html.erb or elsewhere. In manufacturers/index.html.erb it asks for the `:manufacturer_id` so i tried different ways and no luck. perhaps I'm missing something here.

these are my routes

```
    Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                        Controller#Action
    root GET  /                                                  manufacturers#index
    manufacturer_cars GET  /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/cars(.:format)     cars#index
    POST /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/cars(.:format)     cars#create
    new_manufacturer_car GET  /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/cars/new(.:format) cars#new
    manufacturer_car GET  /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/cars/:id(.:format) cars#show
    manufacturers GET  /manufacturers(.:format)                           manufacturers#index
    POST /manufacturers(.:format)                           manufacturers#create
    new_manufacturer GET  /manufacturers/new(.:format)                       manufacturers#new
    manufacturer GET  /manufacturers/:id(.:format)                       manufacturers#show
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: `new_manufacturer_car GET  /manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/cars/new(.:format)`

means that there really should be a manufacturer id passed in your link.
It should be called like `new_manufacturer_car_path(manufacturer)` or
`new_manufacturer_car_path(manufacturer_id: 1)`

Comment: so when i run ```new_manufacturer_car_path(manufacturer_id: 1)``` I get this error ```No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"cars", :manufacturers_id=>1} missing required keys: [:manufacturer_id]```

Comment: and running ```new_manufacturer_car_path(manufacturer) I get this one ```undefined local variable or method `manufacturers' for #<#<Class:0x007fe077c97a70>:0x007fe077c94280>``` or ```undefined local variable or method `manufacturer' for #<#<Class:0x007fe077c97a70>:0x007fe078922498>``` @user3243476